# Making Node js apps https secure

Tags: node.js, express, https, blockchain

I am creating a chaincode project , in which nodejs is consuming the chaincoe smartcontract. 
My project structure includes index.js - swagger specs , app.js - to consumer swagger specs and bin/www - where http specification is defined .
I have defined http with basic auth and it works fine. For making all the services https secure , I have downloaded open ssl in my linux machine and have generated the certificate and the private key. (https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

I have made changes in the bin/www.js for the https part :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

require("dotenv").config();
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem').toString();
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
app.set('port', port);
var hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME;

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

https.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

but this is not working . I have also imported the certificate and key in the mozilla. Request all to kindly help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not used privatekey and certificate in connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `key` and `cert` to the `createServer` function.

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString();
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem').toString();
}

https
.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
})
.listen(443, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on localhost:443");
});
```

Now, as @aditi said in the comments, the callback in `createServer` is a request handler. That means it will trigger when there is a `request` event. A request event is triggered by mostly HTTP requesting the server. So, if you open `localhost:443` it will show you the `"hello world"` text.

If you want to console log something when the server is started (listing) you need to add the callback in the `listen` function. Which you have done.

Comment: I modified my create server function by adding a few logs:   https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log("Inside HTTPS creation");
  console.log("server running at https://localhost:8443/")
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8443);
console.log("Exit HTTPS creation");    but somehow , it is not entering the loop . Any help on this please.

Comment: That's because the `createServer` callback is a request handler. That means opening `localhost:443` will trigger the callback I am editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it worked ,

I used

```
https.createServer(httpsOptions,app)
.listen(port,function(){
  console.log("Inside HTTPS creation");
})
```

Thanks all.